# How to check if a list contains only boolean value

Tags: python

I want to write a function:

```
def CheckBoolean(lst):
```

if the list only contains True or False, it will return True, otherwise it will return False

Comment: Why are you enumerating?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python built-in function [**`all`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) for this.

```
result = all(isinstance(item, bool) for item in last)
```

---

> `all` return `True` if all elements of the iterable are true **(or if the
> iterable is empty).**

Answer (score 1):

```
def CheckBoolean(lst):
    return all(isinstance(i, bool) for i in lst)
```